# How to resolve "UNKNOWN:Timer list shutdown" error?

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I operate Cloud Functions on GCP, and the job is written in Python. I encountered the following error message last day.

It seems to be an error of Kubernetes, and does anyone know the cause of this issue? Is it because of the shortage of the resource of GKE?

```
{
insertId: "-"
jsonPayload: {
message: " run_poller: UNKNOWN:Timer list shutdown {created_time:"2023-03-14T16:28:27.200506461+00:00"}"
pid: "75"
}
labels: {
compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: "-"
k8s-pod/controller-uid: "-"
k8s-pod/job-name: "-"
}
logName: "-"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-03-14T16:28:32.194472183Z"
resource: {
labels: {6}
type: "k8s_container"
}
severity: "ERROR"
sourceLocation: {
file: "backup_poller.cc"
line: "122"
}
timestamp: "2023-03-14T16:28:27.213678702Z"
}

I looked for the cause of this issue by using the internet but cannot find any useful information. I want to specify the reason of this issue and resolve it.
```

Comment: What's the relation with Cloud Functions? It looks like a K8S issue

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is an error log of a function of Cloud Functions but seems to be an issue of k8s. Do you know the cause of this kind of issue?

Comment: What's your Cloud Logging filter?

Comment: After my investigation, I assume that it possibly because of the shortage of memory. I will increase the memory size and wait and see for a while. Thank you for your help.